# Why are the fonts all screwy for remote X11 apps on one Mac client?

Tags: fonts, xorg, xforwarding

I have two Mac OS X clients, both running XQuartz 2.1.6 (xorg-server 1.4.2-apple33). When I SSH into a remote linux system enabling X11 forwarding and launch gnome-terminal, on one Mac the terminal looks correct while on the other, the fonts are all screwy!

`[jnet@Stan ~]$ ssh -X jnet@kyle.local gnome-terminal` produces:
[image: Lookin good!]

`powerbook:~ hp$ ssh -X jnet@kyle.local gnome-terminal` produces:
[image: OH MY GOD, MY EYES!!!!!]

The problem goes away on the powerbook if I zoom in twice:
[image: Looks OK only because the image is scaled down to fit]

**Edit:** This affects a number of apps, not just gnome-terminal. It also affects Thunderbird, for example.